# React-Native Geolocation doesn't work as expected on Android

Tags: facebook, geolocation, react-native

When looking at [the source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/09820cbe363e0bcdc73cd3ef0733a63f0cdaeb16/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/location/LocationModule.java) of Geolocation library I cannot find what is the wrong. (also I don't know Java lang)

I've installed UIExplorer on a real Android device.

When I open UIExplorer Geolocation page initial and current position seems as unknown. Then it pops an alert as `undefined`.

Also I try Geolocation module on my own test app. It cannot determine my location.

However, when I walk, *after 50 meters* it determines my location.

What can I do to overcome this issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: Thank you. The code is [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/GeolocationExample.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I'd tried another Android phone before. I don't know why but after restart the phone it started to work!